# install issue with pip

Tags: python, django, pip

when i install a package with pip, pip show the successful message but i can't import it 
and i can't add it to INSTALLED_APPS, the program does not recognize it

```
pip install django-ckeditor
```

WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
WARNING: The directory '/home/def/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: django-ckeditor in /home/def/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (5.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: django-js-asset>=1.2.2 in /home/def/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from django-ckeditor) (1.2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running
`pip install --user django-ckeditor`

Also, try to update pip if needed before running again. Maybe packages are not updated properly.